# SharePoint Online modern sites have an issue with URL contains spaces

Tags: sharepoint, service-worker, sharepoint-online

Our customers(at least two from different regions) have reported an issue with access to SharePoint sites which contain spaces in URL. After open some sites in new tab, they get[image]

After some investigation we have found that SharePoint sites register Service Worker in browser.
[image]

The Service Worker intercepts all requests going from current page, apply some logic and one of the branch in the logic leads to the error.
Let me explain what happens:
When you have custom home page on a site, and you navigate to the root site URL like https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite, SharePoint will automatically redirect you to the custom home page like https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/SitePages/MyCustomHP.aspx
All these requests are handled by the Service Worker and it treats this redirect as a trigger for re-authentication and sends you to Authenticate.aspx
[image]
In order, Authenticate.aspx works incorrectly:
[image]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open any modern team site(in Edge or Chrome, I tried in Edge)
   (like https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-team)
2. Create a modern subsite with spaces and navigate to it.
   (for example https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-team/Site with spaces)
3. Open Pages library on the subsite and create custom Site Page
4. Make it as Home page
5. Open new tab and paste the URL [https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Site with spaces]

The Result you can see above. Hmmm... can't reach this page

**Questions:**

1. Why does Authenticate.aspx works incorrectly ?
2. May be the logic in Service Worker is wrong? and such kind of redirects should not lead re-authentication or it should encode parameters to Authenticate.aspx by other way?
3. When will it be fixed :) ?

**Possible Workarounds**

1. Clear IndexedDB/Route.Config in dev tools and restart Service Worker
2. Change the URL and remove spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has fixed their code of Service Worker in 2021-08-27 release
Now, the previously buggy code, looks like:
[image]
As you can see double encoding check was added

[image]

How it looked before you can check above.